# Deluge on raspbian: adding torrent through web ui is awfully slow

Tags: raspbian, deluge

I am testing deluged on my new Raspberry 2, confident it would run perfectly since it works on far lower spec  machinnes (Seagate FreeAgent Dockstar for example).
Download speeds are good and it doesn't bog the raspi down when working.
The only problem I have is that if I upload a torrent through the web-ui it takes a couple of minutes, during which CPU use for deluge-web goes near 100%.
This happens only when uploading a torrent file with the web ui, I tried the following without any issue (instant upload of the torrent as expected):

- upload through a remote desktop client
- adding the torrent using an URL (either through web-ui or deluge-console, local and remote)

The torrent I am testing is an Ubuntu one, around 44KB in all; my deluge version is 1.3.11 (but had the same problem with 1.3.3), os is raspbian, text mode.